# Mouseover once not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have:

```
<html><head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#hoverit").one("mouseover", function(){
 $("#tomato").append('t'); 
});
</script>
</head><body>
<div id="hoverit">hover over this</div>
<div id="tomato">mmm</div>
</body></html>
```

I'm trying to make a mouse hover do an action once only using the jquery `one` command and it's not working...

Any ideas?

Comment: You are trying to bind the event handler before the element exists. This is covered in the [`Getting started with jQuery` tutorial](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Getting_Started_with_jQuery).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try :

```
<html><head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.min.js"></script> 

</head><body>
<div id="hoverit">hover over this</div>
<div id="tomato">mmm</div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#hoverit").one("mouseover", function(){
 $("#tomato").append('t'); 
});
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: `$("#hoverit").one("mouseover", function(){` should come AFTER the creation , unless you use live ( or 'on' in 1.7+)

Comment: @David19801: Because the element already exists at the time the code gets executed. HTML is parsed from top to bottom.

Answer (score 0):

either use the @Royi Namir solution that is to put the js at the end of your html or use [`ready`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) handler, the reason your code is not working is because its fired when the DOM is not ready or the elements to which you have bounded the events to are no created when the handler code fires, the solution is to put the js at the end or use [`$(document).ready();`](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials%3aIntroducing_%24%28document%29.ready%28%29)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#hoverit").one("mouseover", function(){
 $("#tomato").append('t'); 
});
});
</script>
```